# How to maintain the default font size of Windows Forms application even after the entire Windows Text size is changed from Small to Medium?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application where the font size changes based on the text size is changed for the entire windows. How do I maintain the default font size in my Windows Form application even the text size for entire windows is changed from Small to Medium ? I already used AutoScalMode to None, but the font size overlaps a control if they are very close to each other.

[image: overlap controls]

Thanks

Comment: You explicitly do *not* want to set the AutoScaleMode to None.  It must be Font to get your form to scale properly.  Ensure that the form's Font is set correctly and that controls just inherit the form's Font.  Right-click their Font property and hit Reset.

Comment: those properties are ambient ones if you dont set them they inherit from container,do you set the font for the form or just the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a common problem with WinForms.

If I understood your problem - problem occurs when you manually set font in WinForms control f.e. Label.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978597/2029818), i'd written code below. Maybe it would help

Getting actual Dpi display size:

```
public class FontResizeFactorProvider
    {
        private const int DpiSmallSize = 96;
        private const int DpiMediumSize = 120;
        private const int DpiLargeSize = 144;

        public float GetFontResizeFactor()
        {
            var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr desktop = graphics.GetHdc();

            var displayDimensions = new List<int>
                {
                    GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int) DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSX),
                    GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int) DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSY)
                };

            var matchedDim = displayDimensions.First(dim => dim == DpiSmallSize || dim == DpiMediumSize || dim == DpiLargeSize);

            if (matchedDim == default(int))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Dpi size not standard.");
            }

            var resizeFactor = (float) DpiSmallSize/matchedDim;

            return resizeFactor;
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hDC, int nIndex);

        public enum DeviceCap
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Logical pixels inch in X
            /// </summary>
            LOGPIXELSX = 88,
            /// <summary>
            /// Logical pixels inch in Y
            /// </summary>
            LOGPIXELSY = 90

            // Other constants may be founded on pinvoke.net
        }
    }
```

Service responsible for re-sizing fonts in Form:

```
public class FormFontsResizeService
    {
        private const double EPSILON = 0.1;
        private readonly FontResizeFactorProvider _fontResizeFactorProvider;

        public FormFontsResizeService():this(new FontResizeFactorProvider())
        {
        }

        public FormFontsResizeService(FontResizeFactorProvider fontResizeFactorProvider)
        {
            _fontResizeFactorProvider = fontResizeFactorProvider;
        }

        public void ResizeControlFonts(Form form)
        {
            var resizeFactor = _fontResizeFactorProvider.GetFontResizeFactor();

            foreach (Control control in form.Controls)
            {
                var baseFont = control.Font;

                if (Math.Abs(baseFont.Size - SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Size) < EPSILON)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var scaledFont = new Font(baseFont.FontFamily, baseFont.Size*resizeFactor, baseFont.Style);
                control.Font = scaledFont;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage in Form:

```
protected override void OnShown(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var formFontsResizeService = new FormFontsResizeService();
            formFontsResizeService.ResizeControlFonts(this);
        }
```

Also Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123073/winforms-different-sizes-in-different-environments).