# Winform window display and behavior change when connecting an extra display monitor

Tags: c#, winforms

EDIT to address the "duplicate":
This question is about the differences in display when plugging and unplugging an extra monitor. The "duplicate" is when the DPI changes in a monitor or an application is run on a different monitor. Although related, the situation is different.
I am asking **specifically** when the app is run on the *same* PC

I usually work with a notebook connected to a bigger display. The resolutions are notebook: 150%  1920x1080 and extra 100% 1280x1024.

Lately I have developed a winform application that uses multiple forms. It works well. However the other day for a demonstration, I disconnected the extra display and took my notebook. When I run the application the forms dimension got completely wrong. Sometimes buttons that were on some place disappeared since the form got smaller and I had to manually make them bigger to see the button.

Even stranger, I am using some dataGridViews (with checkboxes inside) and they worked well. But when the extra display is disconnected, when I click on a checkbox the behavior is all wrong in the beginning.

Has anyone have this type of issues? What could be causing this? And how to solve it?

I repeat that this happens when multiple forms are being called as in

```
PForm1 f = new PForm1();

if (f.ShowDialog()!=DialogResult.OK) {
    //...
}

PForm2 f2 = new PForm2();

if (f2.ShowDialog()!=DialogResult.OK) {
    //...
}
//....
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms different sizes in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123073/winforms-different-sizes-in-different-environments)

Comment: @mjwills I read the "duplicate". Does the DPI of a display change when connecting an extra monitor? If no, then it is not a duplicate

Comment: `Does the DPI of a display change when connecting an extra monitor?` It can, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be the same issue that I recently experienced.  In my case the issue was actually due to where Visual Studio was running when the app was compiled.  If I ran VS on the monitor that was *not* 100% DPI, then the resulting app would look messed up on any other DPI.  However, when I only used VS on the 100% DPI monitor to compile the app, the app would look fine on other DPIs such as 150% and 200%.  Note, that if you try to run the app on some DPI like 175% you would prob still have an issue, and I don't think there would be any good way around this.