# Issue with Winforms Controls Shifting On Some Computers

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am running into an issue where on one of my user's pc (Win10) the comboboxes are being shifted.  On the left is how they look in the user control and on the left is how they are displayed to the user.  They have the same display settings as the other users, so same screen resolution, scale, and orientation.  I checked the anchoring for the dropdownlist and it is anchored the same as the textboxes.  I am at a loss at what to check next to see where the issue is and hoping someone might know something else I can check.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123073/winforms-different-sizes-in-different-environments

Comment: *They have the same display settings as the other users, so same screen resolution, scale, and orientation* - Have you checked the DPI as well? Note the answers in the linked question.

Comment: I will take a look at the links to see if I missed some setting, specifically how WinForms handles autoscaling.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I was able to recreate the issue on my pc by changing my scaling to anything over 100%, but it seemed odd that the pc in question has scaling set to 100%.  I double-checked a few times to be sure.  I guess I need to see if there is anywhere else I can set the scaling or DPI outside the display settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank @brennan208 for his help in troubleshooting the issue.  After a bit of discussion with Telerik they pointed me to their documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/knowledge-base/hdpi-tips-and-tricks#general-tips-for-designing-scalable-winforms) that has general tips for designing scalable WinForms.  What I needed to do was place my controls in a TableLayoutPanel, so now when I change the scaling the controls correctly scale as well.  Painful lesson and I hope the article helps others.  Thanks.

Wade